# how to convert a list into string in tcl

Tags: tcl

How do I convert a list into string in Tcl?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

most likely what you want is [join](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1478) however depending on what you are trying to do this may not be necessary.

[anything in TCL is able to be treated as a string at anytime](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018), consequently you may be able to just use your list as a string without explict conversion

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the contents, you can puts $listvar and it will write out the contents as a string.

You can flatten the list by one level or insert a separator character by using join, as jk answered above.

Example:

```
% set a { 1 2 3 4 { 5 6 { 7 8 9 } } 10 }
 1 2 3 4 { 5 6 { 7 8 9 } } 10 
% puts $a
 1 2 3 4 { 5 6 { 7 8 9 } } 10 
% join $a ","
1,2,3,4, 5 6 { 7 8 9 } ,10
% join $a
1 2 3 4  5 6 { 7 8 9 }  10
```

Comment: If you need to flatten multi level lists too, have a look at the Tcllib struct::list package and the flatten subcommand. http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_list.html

Answer (score 1):

```
set list {a b c d e f}
for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $list]} {incr i} {
    append string [lindex $list $i]
}
puts $string
```

Answer (score 1):

To flatten a list using classes:

```
set list { 1 2 3 4 { 5 6 { 7 8 9 } } 10 }

package require struct::list
struct::list flatten -full $list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

% join {a b c} " and "

a and b and c

% join {a b c} ""

abc

(source: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/join)

Answer (score -1):

```
set a { 1 2 3 4 { 5 6 { 7 8 9 } } 10 }
set rstr [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $a]
puts $rstr
```

Answer (score -7):

Use the list command.

http://wiki.tcl.tk/440

Alternatively, see "split": http://wiki.tcl.tk/1499

```
split "comp.unix.misc"
```

returns "comp unix misc"

Comment: You are giving ways to make a list from a string.  The question asks for the opposite - how to get from list to string.